# yii2 консольное обращение не к папке commands

Tags: php, yii2

Приветствую всех вошедших

По средствам консоли охота сделать обращение не к папке commands, а к классу лежащему в другой папке ( в моем случае testpack )

Можно ли такое реализовать?

p.s.
Ну ест-но средствами yii2, без классических приёмов php include/require )

**UPD**

```
//дополнительная папка с контроллерами в YII2 basic
'controllerMap' => [
    'command' => [
        'class' => 'yii\testpack\PrivetController',
        'namespace' => 'privet',
      ],
],

//обращение php yii privet
//сам контроллер - копия hello world, только переписано на privet. из родной папки ест-но работает, а вот из testpack - нет

//файл ест-но на месте
$ php yii privet
An Error occurred while handling another error:
exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Class yii\testpack\PrivetController does not exist'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Исправляю ответ, скорее всего вы не так сделали, сделал только что у себя демо, у меня работает !
Давайте по порядку. Config

```
'controllerMap' => [
    'test' => [
        'class' => 'frontend\controllers\TestController',
    ],
],
```

где значение 'class' это путь к вашему контроллеру

И сам контроллер

```
namespace frontend\controller;
use yii\console\Controller;
class TestController extends Controller 
{   
     public function actionShow()
     {
            echo 12345;
     }
}
```

Да, забыл сказать, скорее всего по этому и была ошибка, контроллер в обязательном порядке должен быть унаследован от

```
yii\console\Controller
```

Вот и все, запускается командой ./yii test/show. Так как у вас basic, пропишите правильные пути к файлам

Comment: эта папка действительно есть, правда в basic версии yii2. Наверно Ваш совет для advanced версии

Comment: да, но сути это не меняет, этот конфиг находится тогда в config/console.php

Comment: собственно попробовал сделать по вашему описанию, к сожалению не сработало. при обращении из консоли php yii privet ( PrivetController ) ошибки, что контроллер не найден

Comment: покажите что вы поменяли и скиньте ошибку целиком

Comment: Смотрите, ответ обновил